# Import in Rails Admin problems with belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, import-from-csv

In my app i use rails_admin and install rails_admin_import.

Model 'Team' :id, :name, :image_url, and belongs_to Sports.

If i try import CSV 
id, name, image_url, sport_id
1, Toronto, , 1

Program created new record but sport is Null.

Answer (score 0):

I was using rails_admin_import 1.3.0 and specified "Related fields mapping" to appropriate column in the other table.  It worked for me.